How to compress a 100GB video effectively to smoothly play it on TV via Google Chromecast
How to compress a 100GB video effectively to smoothly play it on TV via Google Chromecast?
The video is 2160p converted from BlueRay disk.
The video is on my Macbook Pro computer and I play it with VLC Player or Airflow app and project it to TV via Chromecast.

failed attempt #1: Splitting it into 5GB parts and play them separately. It still have pauses every few seconds.

